# Django Unable to Retrieve Session Data in APIView

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm having trouble retrieving session data in a Django APIView. I have two API endpoints: LoginVerification and BucketSize. The LoginVerification endpoint successfully sets session data, but when I try to access the session data in the BucketSize endpoint, the session appears to be empty.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

## views.py

```
class LoginVerification(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    @csrf_exempt
    def post(request):
        # ... code to verify AWS credentials and set session data ...
        data = request.data
        aws_access_key = data.get('accessKey', '')
        aws_secret_key = data.get('secretKey', '')
        aws_region = data.get('region', '')
        aws_bucket = data.get('bucket', '')
        print("session items --- ",request.session.items())

        
        return Response({"verification": aws_verification})

class BucketSize(APIView):
    @csrf_exempt
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            # Attempting to retrieve session data, but it appears empty               
            print("session items --- ",request.session.items())
            return Response({'status': 'success', 'bucketsize': bucketsize, 'unit': unit})
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'status': 'error', 'error': str(e)})
```

In the LoginVerification class, I set the session data, and it appears to be stored correctly as I can print the session items.

```
session items ---  dict_items([('aws_access_key', 'JBSHSDNIARPSRMT'), ('aws_secret_key', 'cruewYu0TnusgfCSDcbPuO7hYV'), ('aws_region', 'eu-central-1'), ('aws_bucket', 'bucketname')])
```

However, when I try to retrieve the session data in the BucketSize class, the session appears to be empty. The request.session.items() call returns an empty dictionary. I have confirmed that the SessionMiddleware is enabled in my MIDDLEWARE setting.

```
session items ---  dict_items([])
```

This is my URL.py --

```
urlpatterns = [path('bucket-size/', BucketSize.as_view(), name='bucket-size'),path('login-verification/', LoginVerification.as_view()),]
```

Also, im using react js as frontend --

Am I missing something in my code or configuration that could be causing this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = async (e) => {
        const text = e.target.result;
        console.log("Raw text from file: ", text);
        try {
          const jsonData = JSON.parse(text);
          console.log("Parsed JSON data: ", jsonData);
          const formData = {
            accessKey: jsonData.AwsAccessKey,
            secretKey: jsonData.AwsSecretKey,
            region: jsonData.AwsRegion,
            bucket: jsonData.AwsBucket,
          };
          console.log("Form data: ", formData);

          axios
            .post(backendUrl, formData,)
            .then((response) => {
              console.log("Request successful, response data: ", response.data);
              setVerificationResult(response.data.verification);
              onAuthenticate(response.data);

              // Only show the alert if the result is not "Connected"
              if (response.data.verification !== "Connected") {
                setShowAlert(true);
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Request failed, error: ", error);
              console.error(error);
              setVerificationResult("Failed to connect to backend");
              setShowAlert(true);
              console.log("showAlert after axios post error", showAlert);
            });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error parsing JSON", error);
        }
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Do you each time send an auth token?

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike Im using a session based authentication here. So, everytime i log in, the credentials are updated in the session.